# Update form not working in table

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, html-table

I'm trying to use AJAX / jQuery to add, delete, and update rows of a table.  The add and delete functions work fine. When I try to update a row though, the form doesn't create a patch request (or really do anything - no activity in the server log, JS console, or network activity.  For a row, the user clicks a button to replace the row with an update form, but when data is changed in the form and the user clicks submit nothing happens.  When I take the form out of the table, it works.  Is there a problem with doing this in a table?  Thanks for the help!

Here is the form_tag I'm using.

```
<tr id = <%= "site_#{@site.id}" %>
 <%= form_tag site_url(@site.id), method: "patch", remote: true, id: "site_form_#{@site.id}" do %>
 <td><%= link_to (image_tag @site.favicon), "http://www.#{@site[:company].delete(" ")}.com", target: "_blank" %><%= text_field_tag :company, @site.company %></td>
 <td><%= text_field_tag :username_sb, (@site.username_sb.decrypt ENV['SB_DECRYPT']) %></td>
 <td><%= text_field_tag :pwhint_sb, (@site.pwhint_sb.decrypt ENV['SB_DECRYPT']) %></td>
 <% hidden_field_tag :id, @site.id %>
 <td><%= button_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-inverse" %></td>
 <td></td>
 <% end %>
</tr>
```

Here is the entire table it's being inserted into.

```
<div class= "row-fluid">
  <div class= "span10 offset1">
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Password hint</th>
          <th> </th>
          <th> </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="add">
          <%= render 'form_new', :site => Site.new %>
        </tr>
       <% @sites_sort.each do |site| %>
     <%= render 'site', :site => site %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the jQuery I'm using to convert the row to an edit form.

```
$('#site_<%= @site.id %>').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render 'edit_one_form') %>');
```

Here is the jQuery I'm using to update the view. (Although it's never getting to this code)

$('#site_<%= @site.id %>').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render 'site', :site => @site) %>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The separation of the form by opening and closing td html tags was preventing the form from submitting properly after inserted with JS.  Instead, I rendered each site as its own table, so instead the update function removed one table, inserted the form in its place, and re-rendered an updated table via jQuery / AJAX.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" id="site_table_<%= site.id %>">
  <tr class = "rowhover" id="site_<%= site.id %>">
    <td id="td_company_site" class="cell cell-vert-align"><strong>
        <%= link_to (image_tag site.favicon, class:"site_favicon"), "http://www.#{site.site.gsub("http://www.","")}", target: "_blank" %>
        <%= link_to " #{site[:company]}", "http://www.#{site.site.gsub("http://www.","")}", target: "_blank" %></strong>
    </td>
    <td id="td_username_site" class="cell cell-vert-align"><%= site.username_sb.decrypt ENV['SB_DECRYPT'] %></td>
    <td id="td_pwhint_site" class="cell cell-vert-align"><%= site.pwhint_sb.decrypt ENV['SB_DECRYPT'] %></td>
    <td id="td_edit"><%= link_to '<i class="icon-edit"></i>'.html_safe, edit_site_url(site.id), class: "btn btn-warning button-hover btn-small", remote: true %></td>
    <%= form_tag site_url(site.id), remote: true, method: "delete" do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :site_id, site.id %>
    <td id="td_delete"><%= button_tag '<i class="icon-remove"></i>'.html_safe, class: "btn btn-danger button-hover btn-small", id: 'new' %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<table>
```